# how do i convert unix time stamp to formatted date while using json_extract_scalar in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

for example i have this

```
SELECT  
JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(jsonBlob, '$.userName') as userName,
JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(jsonBlob, '$.Id') as id,
JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(jsonBlob, '$.CreatedDateTime') as CreatedDateTime,
from dataset.tableName
```

this gives me back the a result but the CreatedDateTime field is in unix time stamp, i want to get it in 2018-02-01 17:11:43 format. i know i can use

```
SELECT MSEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(CreatedDateTime) as CreatedDateTime
```

to convert it later, but what if i want to do this in the above select statement.
any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  MSEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(INTEGER(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(jsonBlob, '$.CreatedDateTime'))) as CreatedDateTime
```

above is for Legacy SQL as looks like it is what you use in your question

forgot to mention  - for BigQuery Standard SQL , the same will look like below

```
SELECT 
  TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(CAST(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(jsonBlob, '$.CreatedDateTime') AS INT64)) as CreatedDateTime
```

Comment: Thank you this defiantly worked,(Legacy sql) 
is there an equivalent function in standard sql ?

Comment: yes. see in my answer  - and consider voting up if it was helpful - which looks like it was :o)